# One-hot encoding of large dataset with scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a large dataset which I plan to do logistic regression on. It has lots of categorical variables, each having thousands of features which I am planning to use one hot encoding on. I will need to deal with the data in small batches. My question is how to make sure that one hot encoding sees all the features of each categorical variable during the first run?

Comment: This is a common problem with one hot encodings; the answer is that there is no good way to handle cases when new categories are introduced in the testing set.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way around finding out which possible values your categorical features can take, which probably implies that you have to go through your data fully once in order to obtain a list of unique values of your categorical variables.

After that it is a matter of transforming your categorical variables to integer values and setting the `n_values=` kwarg in `OneHotEncoder` to an array corresponding to the number of different values each variable can take.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the data and first get a list of all the unique values of your categorical variables. Then you can fit a one hot encoder object (like the sklearn.preprocessing.CategoricalEncoder) on your list of unique values.

This method can help in

- a train test framework
- or when you are reading your data in chunks

I have created a python module that does all this on its own. You can find it in this GitHub repository - [dummyPy](https://github.com/yashu-seth/dummyPy)

A short a tutorial on this - [How to One Hot Encode Categorical Variables of a large dataset in Python?](https://yashuseth.wordpress.com/2017/12/14/how-to-one-hot-encode-categorical-variables-of-a-large-dataset-in-python/)